# Nicht-Sympathisant

Tags: synonym

Kurz:
Was wäre die richtige Bezeichnung für einen "Nicht-Sympathisanten"?

Lang:
Man kann der Gegner einer Meinung sein. Man kann aber auch Befürworter einer Meinung sein.
Man kann der Meinung jedoch auch neutral gegenüber eingestellt sein. Dafür gibt es sicher eine Bezeichnung, mir fällt sie jedoch nicht ein.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Meine Präferenz wäre **ein Indifferenter** bzw. **eine Indifferente**.

Mithilfe einer Suchmaschine finden sich dazu im Web auch eine ganze Reihe von Beispielen:

> Politisch heisst das: Wie bewege ich die Indifferenten?

["Die Indifferenten bewegen", in: Die Politik 6/2012](http://www.die-politik.ch/de/archiv/ausgabe-6-2012/artikel/661_die-indifferenten-bewegen/)

und viele andere. Allerdings sind fast alle Verwendungen im Plural. In der Einzahl gibt es nur wenige Fundstellen:

> Ein leidenschaftsloser, ein Indifferenter, ein Funktionsträger der
>   amerikanischen Schönheitsindustrie.

["Verschlagensein in der Verzweiflung", in: Die Zeit 30/1982](http://www.zeit.de/1982/30/verschlagensein-in-der-verzweiflung)

Es empfiehlt sich daher, dieses ungebräuchliche Substantiv, wenn in der Einzahl verwendet, anhand des Kontextes sorgsam dem Leser nahezubringen.

Natürlich gäbe es noch weitere Möglichkeiten, z.B. **ein(e) Gleichgültige(r)**, **ein(e) Neutrale(r)** usw. Außerdem natürlich die "Uns": ein Unentschiedener/Unentschlossener/...

Habe überlegt, ob es einen ähnlich bildhaften Ausdruck wie den englischen "fence-sitter" gibt, aber nichts gefunden; "Zaungast" ist etwas anderes. "Der zwischen den Stühlen sitzt", wäre doch ein guter Filmtitel, oder?

Comment: Hallo Eugene. Indifferent war mir bisher noch nicht geläufig aber entspricht dem was ich gesucht habe. Bisher ist mir auch der "Gleichgültige" noch nicht in den Sinn gekommen, scheint aber auch nicht abwegig. Danke für deinen Beitrag. *Mission accomplished*

Comment: Finde die deutsche Variante deutlich stimmiger.